# feeding text into two text boxes and marking the same words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields - an `input` of type "text" and a `textarea`.

If the `input` contains the word "dog" and the `textarea` contains the word "underdog", the "dog" in the `textarea` should be marked in red in the `div` with the id "rslt".

How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: There's a missing `}` in your code - you can see the problem if you run the snippet I added to the question

Comment: I see, thanks! Must have happened when I copied it here. Still, I wonder how I can make my case work. Maybe a loop that goes over the words?

Comment: Maybe also by using a span?

Comment: the word should be highlighted in the textarea or in `<div id="rslt"></div>`?

Comment: in the #rslt div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to get the position of the current word in a string then apply some css there. This code handles multiple word highlighting.

```js
function markText(text, word, index) {
        if (index != -1) {
            var left = text.substr(0, index);
            var current = word;
            var right = text.substr(index + word.length);
            var current = '<span style="background-color: red">' + current + '</span>';
            text = left + current + right;
            if (right.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                text = markText(text, word, (left + current).length + right.indexOf(word));
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        if (($('#txtarea').val() == "") || ($('#bx').val() == "")) {
            $('#rslt').html('Please fill both boxes!');
            return;
        }
        var words = $('#bx').val().split(' ');
        var text = $('#txtarea').val();

        words.forEach(function (word) {
            if (text.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                text = markText(text, word, text.indexOf(word));
            }
        });

        $("#rslt").html(text); //WHAT HERE?
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Write here:</p>
<input type="text" id="bx"/><br/>
<p>and here:</p>
<textarea cols="100" rows="8" id="txtarea"></textarea><br/>
<button id="btn">GO</button>
<hr/>
<div id="rslt"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping me! Should it work now? Because it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MuliCohen yes it should, run the code snippet it here and see

Comment: Sorry, it was a problem with me software. it work, thanks!

Comment: @MuliCohen I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One more thing, I'd like the text from the text area coppied to the #rslt too, so it will copy to the #rslt the whole text area, and mark in red the words that are also in the box. Can you kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: you want the text in the input to appear in `#rslt` too? as currently the text from the textarea is displayed in the `#rslt`.

Comment: I used the wrong Jquery library. Sorry for wasting your precious time and thanks again!